# Pointer to a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates

I wrote a simple template class, which works fine, if the objects are created without using pointers. However if I need to create a pointer to that class object, I get `error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘Logger<int>*’ [-fpermissive]`. I am attaching the code below. Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Logger
{
    public:
        Logger (const T& d) {data = d;}
        void print(){std::cout << "data: " << data << std::endl;}
    private:
        int data;
};


int main() {
    /*
    // Works
    Logger<int> myLogger(5);
    myLogger.print();
    */

    Logger<int>* myLogger(5);
    myLogger->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is because that is only a pointer to a logger object not some object in itself. You have to do `Logger<int> *myLogger = new myLogger(5);` (and please don't do that, manual memory management sucks. Use std::unique_ptr).

Comment: @Geek -- C++ is not Java.  There is no need to use `new` to create an object.

Comment: This is not unique to templates. I think you may have skipped ahead a bit too far in your C++ book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to allocate a pointer you'd need to use `new` (and remember to `delete` it when it is no longer needed so you don't leak it).

```
Logger<int>* myLogger = new Logger<int>(5);
```

I don't know what your use case is for doing this, but if you really need to dynamically allocate the object, I'd recommend using smart pointers if you can.

```
std::unique_ptr<Logger<int>> myLogger = std::make_unique<Logger<int>>(5);
```

Comment: seems appropriate to use `auto myLogger = ...`